# Chrome Throwing Content Security Policy Error on Google Fonts

Tags: google-chrome, http-headers, webfonts

I've added the Google fonts URL to the font-src directive of my Content-Security-Policy header. I'm getting the following error in Chrome 42:

```
Refused to load the stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
family=Open+Sans:300,400,400italic,600,800|Source+Code+Pro' because it violates the
following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'".
```

My header field looks like this:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; font-src http://fonts.googleapis.com;
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'
```

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that links to `http://fonts.googleapis.com` return stylesheets, not fonts. If you examine the stylesheet it pulls in you'll find several @font-face rules that pull fonts from `http://fonts.gstatic.com`.

To make this work properly, your Content-Security-Policy header should look something like:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; font-src http://fonts.gstatic.com; 
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' http://fonts.googleapis.com
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're like me and a little confused because every answer is just saying you need to authorise a url in a style-src directive without without showing how to do it, here's the full tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="style-src 'self' http://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com;">
```

Answer (score 1):

I found running the `https` variation was a requirement for me:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; font-src https://fonts.gstatic.com; 
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com
```